# % increase calc based value in parameter control?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two sets of string parameter controls: Current Hourly Pay/New Hourly Pay & Current Annual Pay/New Annual Pay.

[image]

and I have a calc field I need to make to track the % increase from current to new pay. I don't want to make a calc for new hourly pay rate % and also one for new annual pay %. Is there some sort of OR statement that I could do to check both sets of controls to do the % increase calc?

something like:

```
if [current hourly rate] = 0
    then ([new hourly rate]-[current hourly rate])/[current hourly rate]
else 
    ([new annual rate]-[current annual rate])/[current annual rate]
end
```

is this possible?

Comment: Did you realize your calculation can divide by zero? That usually doesn't work out well, regardless of the tool :-)

Comment: @AlexBlakemore how would you go about checking for an input or not? Also I know I have the wrong tag for this question, but it wouldn't let me input regular #tableau

Comment: Parameters take a single value. I don’t think they can be null (the absence of a value), but a string can be empty. You could have a boolean parameter also to note which case applies